My app is rejected from Android app review due to permission USE_EXACT_ALARM even after deleting it
I make USE_EXACT_ALARM permission as comment after rejecting my app from Android app review.
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />   -->

After doing that, my app is live successfully.
However I've changed some code and re-submit my app, my my app is rejected due to sensitive permission USE_EXACT_ALARM even if I make it as comment.
So I completely delete this as using tools:node="remove", since it could be used from package that I use in my app.
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" tools:node="remove" />

But I'm still not clear why my app is rejected even though I don't use this permission.
And after I used this permission, my app review time becomes too long like 3-4 days.
Before it takes less than a day.
Please help me.

Google's app review process is pretty bad (but not as bad as Apple's). Sometimes you get a try-hard reviewer who finds issues with your app that aren't even there. I'd just add a comment and resubmit. ETA - in my experience, review times are usually less than 24 hrs, but I've had them take up to 5ish days. It seems pretty random.

I think you need to make sure that there's no packages/libraries requires that permission in your app

@Rob What you say add a comment means contacting to Google Support Team through mail right?

@AhmadDarwesh So if I set tools:node="remove" then packages/libraries can't use it based on my understanding.

Make sure you don't have this permission in test track apps. If so, update them also with tools:node remove. Otherwise just try again (bump just the version numer). Exact alarms is one of the things Google and their bots fight against.
